# Android purpose of Handler Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I was just wondering why the Handler has to take an instance of a Runnable ? After all a Handler purpose is place work from one thread into another Thread. What is the purpose of using a Third thread, a Runnable to accomplish this ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But reading [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your confusion: You're thinking that a `Runnable` object is in itself an instance of a separate `Thread`. It is not. In simple terms it is just an object that, by implementing the `Runnable` interface, a `Thread` you pass it to knows it can execute the code inside it by calling `.run()` on it.

When you send a `Runnable` object to the `Handler`, that `Runnable` is executed in the `Handler`'s `Thread`.

In simple terms it's probably sufficient to explain it this way: If you want to supply a `Handler` with some work to do on its own `Thread`, then you have to supply that piece of code inside an object. Now, the object you supply to the `Handler` has to implement some kind of `interface` so that the `Handler` knows what methods to call in that object to make it do the stuff it needs to do. In basic terms that's what the `Runnable` interface does: it is mandatory for an object that implements `Runnable` to implement the `run()` method.

Comment: Perfect makes real sense. Thank you.